# Transclude content containing more content to translude in a child component

Tags: angular, nested, transclusion, ng-content

I have a wrapper component, which wraps its content with a header.
I'm using 2 different `ng-content` components with 2 different selectors in order to transclude some content into the bordered area, and some content into the header line (actions, etc.).

The `wrapper.component.html` code looks something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ng-content select=".header"></ng-content>
    <ng-content select=".body"></ng-content>
</div>
```

I have a component (let's call it `parent`) using the wrapper, which hosts another component (let's call it `child`) from which I'd also like to transclude content into the header line of the wrapper.

The `parent.component.html` code looks something like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <wrapper>
        <div class="header">    
            <a href="#">Action 1</a>
            <a href="#">Action 2</a>
            <a href="#">Action 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="body">
            Some content
            <child></child>
        </div>
    </wrapper>
</div>
```

And, lastly, the `child.component.html` looks something like this:

```
<div class="child header">
    <a href="#">Action 4</a>
</div>
```

This is not working, meaning that the anchor element for Action 4 is not included in the header area, but rather is left inside the child element's node.
I tried using the `ngProjectAs` attribute, but to no avail.

Is there any way to accomplish this without resorting to dynamic components (e.g. ng-template and the likes) ?